# Mongoose is there a way to get whole document in .distinct()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this code right here which works and distincts all of them with same "manga" but it only returns the "manga" part, not the whole object:

```js
router.get("/lasttw", async (req, res) => {
  const ChapterDocs = await ChapterModel
    .find({})
    .sort({
      createdAt: -1
    })
    .distinct("manga");
  res.json(ChapterDocs)
})
```

Is there a way around for geting the whole object without a second query for each "manga" ?

This is the model that should be distincted and returned:

```
const ChapterSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    number:{type:Number},
    url:{type:String},
    manga:{type:String},
    fansub:{type:String},
}, { timestamps: true })
```

Edit: this code returnes

```
["64a451dfdafa6462651d3ee6","64a4524edafa6462651d3f0c"]
```

but i also need chapter url, fansub and else.

this is the format i want them to be not just "manga" field :

```
{"_id":"64a4871b1c1c012a3ac15ff8"
 ,"number":2
 ,"url":"https://asurascanstr.com/olimposun-oyuncusu-bolum-2/"
 ,"manga":"64a4524edafa6462651d3f0c"
 ,"fansub":"AsuraScans"
 ,"createdAt":"2023-07-04T20:54:51.371Z"
 ,"updatedAt":"2023-07-04T20:54:51.371Z","__v":0}
```

Comment: You want to return the _entire_ collection grouped by `manga`?

Comment: Yeah it's unclear what you are asking for here. By definition, `distinct` logically groups items together. Do you want all of the documents for each group? Just the first one? Something else?

Comment: this returnes ["64a451dfdafa6462651d3ee6","64a4524edafa6462651d3f0c"] which is manga ids, not the whole chapter

Comment: Do you have multiple documents with `manga: "64a451dfdafa6462651d3ee6"`, or `manga: "64a4524edafa6462651d3f0c"`?  If so, which document should be used for returning `number`, `url`, `fansub`, `createdAt`, etc.?  Or do you want all of them?

Comment: yes i have multiple documents with both manga "64a451dfdafa6462651d3ee6"and "64a4524edafa6462651d3f0c". Only the first one that database found of theese instances should return with all of them "url","fansub" etc. i hope i was able to explain. I will update the question for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you have to use `.aggregate` to do stuff like this i found it after some digging. Here is the code :

```js
router.get("/lasttw", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const latestChapters = await ChapterModel.aggregate([
            { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } }, // Sort by createdAt in descending order
            { $group: { _id: "$manga", chapter: { $first: "$$ROOT" } } }, // Group by manga and get the first document (latest chapter) for each manga
            { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$chapter" } }, // Replace the root to get the complete chapter documents
        ]);

        res.json(latestChapters);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred while fetching the latest chapters.' });
    }
});
```

i hope it help anyone trying to do something like this.

1. We use the `aggregate` function to perform a series of operations on the `ChapterModel` collection.
2. We first sort the documents in descending order based on the `createdAt` field using `$sort`.
3. Then we group the sorted documents by the `"manga"` field using `$group`. For each `manga`, we use `$first` to get the first document (which will be the latest chapter).
4. Next, we use `$replaceRoot` to replace the root of each document with the chapter document itself.
5. The `latestChapters` array will contain the latest chapter document for each unique `manga`.
6. The try-catch block is used to handle any potential errors that may occur during the process.

I tried to explain it as best as i can.
Hope it helps